# AJAX, PHP, CSS-Created table sends all form values when only a single row of values is desired

Tags: php, css, ajax, forms

I've followed some suggestions here of using CSS to create a table rather than the table element to create a form for each row of data. The 'table' output is generated by PHP that is called by AJAX. The resulting HTML looks to be correct. I've even used the 'form' attribute on the input elements.  Still, when I click on one submit button in one row, it still sends all rows, causing issues.  HTML below.....Does this look right?

```
<style>
            .table { display: table; } 
            .table>* { display: table-row; }
            .table>*>* { display: table-cell; padding: 5px; border-style: inset;}        
</style>
         <div class="table">
            <div>
               <div><b>Event Id</b></div>
               <div><b>Date</b></div>
               <div><b>@username</b></div>
               <div><b>Sign Up!</b></div>
            </div>
            <form id="form12" method="post">
               <div>12</div>
               <div>Feb-26-2021</div>
               <div><input class="formSignup" type="text" name="pi_username" id="pi_username" maxlength="20" placeholder="@username" form="form12"></div>
               <div><input class="formSignup" type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id" value="12" form="form12">
                  <input name="submit12" type="submit" value="Sign up!" onclick="signup(); return false;">
               </div>
            </form>
            <form id="form13" method="post">
               <div>13</div>
               <div>Feb-27-2021</div>
               <div><input class="formSignup" type="text" name="pi_username" id="pi_username" maxlength="20" placeholder="@username" form="form13"></div>
               <div><input class="formSignup" type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id" value="13" form="form13">
                  <input name="submit13" type="submit" value="Sign up!" onclick="signup(); return false;">
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
```

Comment: You're saying that all forms are submitted, no matter which of the buttons is clicked? Then I believe it's an issue in the way you handle it, since all forms call `signup()`. Can you show that function?

Comment: El Vanja - you are exactly right. The signup was looking for elements with the same class (formSignup). All input fields had the same class name and were all being sent to the signup() function.  I've updated the class name to be unique for each row. Now only a single row is being sent. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The signup() function was looking for elements with the same class (formSignup). All input fields had the same class name and were all being sent to the signup() function. I've updated the class name to be unique for each row. Now only a single row is being sent.

Example of using a unique class name:

<input **class='formSignup" .$row['id']. "'** type='hidden' name='event_id' id='event_id' value='" . $row['id'] . "' form='form" .$row['id']. "'>

The CSS table is being drawn correctly.

Comment: While the solution is working, it's actually all over the place. Your classes are unique, but your ids are the same (it should behave the other way around). You could have simply used this logic for the `id` attribute and omit `class` altogether.

Comment: El_Vanja - thank you for the suggestion. I'll clean it up. Yes, my code is a patchwork of stackoverflow solutions. Total noob here, completely amazed with things people are able to create here.